# Vaadin State Tree Corrupted Exception

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

In my Vaadin (14) application, I have a CRUD view where I am able to route to another view from a button within a row of a GRID.

I navigate to the new view using a click listener:

```
button.getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(SctConstants.PAGE_BUILD_SUB + "/" + programme.getId()));
```

Within the same session, if I create a new a new UI (by opening a new Tab) and then I try and click on the same button in the new UI, the button works as normal to route the application. However in the original UI, if I click on the same button, nothing happens. The application doesn't hang - but a a couple of minutes later, the following exception is thrown:

```
2022-07-20 20:18:16.179 ERROR 16796 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[springServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unregistered node was not found based on its id. The tree is most likely corrupted.
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.unregister(StateTree.java:243) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.handleOnDetach(StateNode.java:759) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.onDetach(StateNode.java:337) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.setParent(StateNode.java:280) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree$RootNode.setParent(StateTree.java:65) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals.setSession(UIInternals.java:400) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.removeUI(VaadinSession.java:594) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.lambda$removeClosedUIs$20ed7015$1(VaadinService.java:1342) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:434) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:395) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.removeClosedUIs(VaadinService.java:1340) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.cleanupSession(VaadinService.java:1304) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.requestEnd(VaadinService.java:1504) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1584) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:252) ~[flow-server-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) ~[vaadin-spring-12.4.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

I am only able to reproduce the error when there is multiple UIs launched. Has anyone got any advice as to how I might solve this? It feels like it is related to the UI Session / UI / Page.

Many thanks

Comment: Not a solution, but I remember that problem and reported a similar problem the past (https://github.com/vaadin/starters/issues/19) - at least in V23 I haven't observed this, if you are eager to update.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back.

Check your Project and remove the "static" modifier from all components that have it. It should fix it.